# Can not import win32com in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

Here's what i've tried:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Then it return this error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9_fuy_o\pypiwin32_779ca7017db54f03b49793052782f425\setup.py", line 121
          print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It seem like it has version conflict in **setup.py**. But when i seeking for this file to fix that: *"C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9_fuy_o\pypiwin32_779ca7017db54f03b49793052782f425\setup.py"*. It not exist. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you try to install `pypiwin32` on Python 3? If you want `win32com` you should install `pywin32`.

Comment: I don't know the solution, the only thing I can add here is that the code above could install pypiwin32 onto my computer.

Comment: No, it can not - as you see. You might be able to install it if you run Python 2, but Python 2 is dead since over three years.

Comment: @Matthias i also tried to install pywin32, but it not working. It show smth like: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

Comment: What Python version are you running?

Comment: @Matthias its Python 3.10.10

Comment: You might have different Python versions installed. Run `python -V` and if that gives you the correct version then try the installation with `python -m pip install pywin32`.

Comment: You may also try to install it as `python -m pip install git+https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32`.